# How to configure PUMA for SSL on JRUBY

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, puma

I have a jruby rails app that is working fine with Puma without SSL. According to Puma's wiki, I have to provide a certificate file and a key file. I got my cert file from GoDaddy and since I am on osx, I extracted the private key from the cert using the Keychain app. I am starting Puma using the following command:

```
bundle exec puma -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:3000?key=file://Users/me/key.p12&cert=file://Users/me/server.x.ca.crt' -t 3:8
```

After that I get a bunch of warnings about redefined SSL constants like this one

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.1/gems/jruby-openssl-0.8.2/lib/shared/jruby-openssl.rb:16 warning: already initialized constant OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER
```

Then this message:

> Puma 1.6.3 starting... 
>   * Min threads: 3, max threads: 8
>   * Environment: development
>   IOError: sun.net.ftp.FtpProtocolException: Welcome message: 
>       initialize at org/jruby/RubyFile.java:333
>         open at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1179
>                 open at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:333
>                 read at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:3611
>                 read at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:3708
>                  run at /Users/me/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.1/gems/puma-1.6.3-java/lib/puma/cli.rb:359
>                 each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612
>                  run at /Users/me/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.1/gems/puma-1.6.3-java/lib/puma/cli.rb:314
>               (root) at /Users/me/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.1/gems/puma-1.6.3-java/bin/puma:10
>                 load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1046
>               (root) at /Users/me/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.1/bin/puma:1
>                 eval at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1066
>               (root) at /Users/me/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.1/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14

And Puma exits. The app runs on my dev machine. I am not using any FTP so I am puzzled by this error message. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [Puma 1.6.x on Jruby do not work with SSL](http://github.com/puma/puma/issues/127) (see the last Evan Phoenix's comment at the bottom of the page). I now use Apache as a reverse proxy to handle SSL in front of Puma.